# error declaring external function with extern pointer

Tags: c, assembly, linker, elf

In my understanding, a symbol in an ELF object file is just a name to a memory address. In other words, given a symbol name, a linker should always refer to the same address no matter what types they are declared in C.

I figured out it wasn't the case. See the example below:

```
/* a.c */
extern void *foo;
extern void *bar;
void main() {
  printf("foo: %p, bar: %p\n", foo, bar)
}

/* b.c */
void foo(void) {
}
void bar(void) {
}
```

The output of above program says `foo` and `bar` point to the same location (1). Also this location is far from what `foo` or `bar`'s address should be. Note (1) indicates it can't be not a conversion mistake

I tried modifying the type of `foo` and `bar` into function pointers (e.g. `extern void (*foo)(void)`), the output is still the same.

It works, of course, with the correct declaration `extern void foo(void)`.

What's mistake I have in my understanding? Thanks. (I'm trying to correct my understanding, not just to make things work)

Comment: "Also this location is far from what foo or bar's address should be" -- what "should" they be?

Comment: @DanFego: I met this problem when compiling with -ffree-standing option, so I could know the exact location of a function.

Comment: Nor sure why you aren't just doing something like `extern void foo(void);` and `extern void bar(void)` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not printing the address that the symbol `foo` and `bar` refer to, but the value at the address of `foo` and `bar`.

To print the address of `foo` and `bar` you need to do something like this:

```
extern void *foo;
extern void *bar;

void main() {
  printf("foo: %p, bar: %p\n", &foo, &bar);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code contains *undefined behaviour* because you declare `foo` and `bar` as identifiers of different type in different translation units. This is a violation of ISO 9899:2011 §6.2.7 ¶2:

> All declarations that refer to the same object or function shall have compatible type;
>   otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

What happens is that when you access a variable in static storage, it is dereferenced to get the value stored at the symbol (which is the content of the global variable). The symbol itself is only the address of the static variable. To get the value of the symbol, you need to use the `&` operator to take the address of the variable, which is the value of the symbol.

Ĺikely being the source of your confusion, this isn't needed for functions, as an `&` is automatically interspersed where needed, cf. ISO 9899:2011 §6.3.2.1 ¶4:

> A *function designator* is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the
>   operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator,<sup>65)</sup> or the unary `&` operator, a function designator with type “function returning *type*” is converted to an expression that has type “pointer to function returning type”.
>
> <sup>65)</sup> Because this conversion does not occur, the operand of the `sizeof` or `_Alignof` operator remains a function designator and violates the constraints in 6.5.3.4.

I hope this clears up your questions.

Answer (score 0):

First thing: the declaration should become

```
void foo(void);
void bar(void);
```

Functions are already extern by default. so you don't need to add extern while declaring in another file. and `extern void *foo` means that you have declared the pointer foo in the other file and using it in this file. but you haven't declared a pointer in the other file as `void *foo`.

And about getting the same address: 2 functions or variables or anything can have a same virtual address but they will be mapped in the different regions of memory(different physical address). wen you print from %p, you get the virtual address and not the physical address.